# como hacer una consulta con un "like" en firebase

Tags: sql, firebase

Saludos estoy intentando hacer una consulta similar a 
select * from where nombre=%dato%, e visto los metodos `startAt` y `endAt` pero no funcionan, se agradece alguna sugerencia

Comment: Creo que una consulta where-like va en contra de la utilidad de una base de datos NoSQL, y hace perder todos los beneficios de la característica *real-time* de Firebase. Sin embargo, si de verdad no tienes otra opción que hacer una busqueda así, te recomiendo investigues sobre ElasticSearch. Es una herramienta de indexación para firebase que ha sido muy útil para los que han enfrentado este problema. Puedes ver este post para mas info: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html

Comment: De verdad que muchas gracias amigo @reekeecast bendiciones